# Adding a Non-Model Form in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to add a non-model form in django admin interface and am not able to find any particular way to do it. This form would do some processing and change some data in the DB. But this is not related to a particular Model and should stand out. This form should not be available for the user to use. 
One thing I can do is add the form to the general view and prohibit using permissions but I was thinking since django admin interface already exists, it would be better to add that to the django admin interface.

Is this possible to do in Django?

Answer (score 4):

You can add arbitrary views that within a ModelAdmin that do whatever you want. See the documentation for [`ModelAdmin.get_urls`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls). You can do the same at a higher level by defining [`AdminSite.get_urls`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites).